# python boto error when inserting data to dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, amazon-dynamodb-streams

```
boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
{'__type': 'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException', 'message': 'One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key restoreid expected: S actual: M'}
```

I have a simple table test with id

All i am trying to do in insert id into the table with String data type. Primary partition key is id(string)

```
 table = Table("test")
 stringjson="{\"id\": {\"S\": \"4343\"}}"
 item_data = json.loads(stringjson)

 table.put_item(data=item_data)
```

I get the error mentioned above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong syntax

look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.01

you should try something like:

```
response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'id': '4343',
    }
)
```

Comment: Eventually i want to insert a Map into the table.

Comment: a Map? or an Item?

Comment: Map as an item. Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419684/dynamodb-boto-put-item-of-type-map-m

Answer (score 0):

The Hash Key of a table in DynamoDB can't be `MAP`. You have a table `test` defined with hash key `id` as String. The error says that the key should be String. Also, no need to specify like this. You can just provide the value in double quotes for String.

```
{\"S\": \"4343\"}
```

**Sample code to add MAP data type:-**

**"quid"** - is the hash key of the table defined as String

"info" - is added as MAP in DynamoDB table

```
jsonString = {"quid": "102",  "info": { "plot": "Nothing happens at all.", "rating": "AA"} }

response = table.put_item(
   Item=jsonString
)
```

**Output:-**

Please refer the below screenshot. The "info" attribute has been added as MAP in DynamoDB table.

[image]